# The correct way to graph of a function on html5-canvas

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas

For self-educational purposes I'm trying to graph math functions on html5-canvas.

I know that there are libraries that can do exactly that, but as I said: educational purpose.

---

**So the question is:** how do I draw a graph of a function for example : **f(x) = 1/x or f(x) = tan(x)**

**The way I tried to do it:**

- loop from (for ex. x = -100 to x == 100)
- calculate value at x
- draw a line from (x, valueAtX) to (x+1, valueAtX_plus1)

**Result:**
[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

---

**If someone could:** give me some pseudocode or steps how to detect if function is continuous at a given point, and then correctly draw it I would appreciate it a lot!

P.S: I've searched for answer for a long time before asking this question, but I couldn't find any, if this question is a duplicate then I'm really sorry, and please link me to the original.

Comment: This is cool - a very well asked question so +1 for that. To make life even easier, could you perhaps provide a fiddle of what you're doing so that we can interact with your code?

Comment: My code is a complete spaghetti + I'm relatively new to the site, I don't know how to add fiddles and such. But I'll try explain everything I can

Comment: I did put it on free hosting, so you can check it out here: http://ensigntrojan.cba.pl/wykresTest.html

Comment: It should normally not happen that for a "sensible" function the value difference is larger than 100 times the x difference. If you detect such a jump, leave out the line for that segment.

Comment: @LutzL, actually, in this case, that is exactly what should happen. The value of `tan(x)` jumps from negative infinity to positive infinity around those points.

Comment: @Ozan: I should have written more explicitly, that this kind of slope does not happen on the continuous segments of the function (on most functions one wants to graph, in the ranges of values one is normally interested in. Of course, the slope 1/cos²(x) of tan(x) can be arbitrarily large at the poles). Other measures are jumps of 90% of the window height etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Dealing with vertical asymptotes.

You need to clip the function at the boundaries. As you are stepping in discrete steps you will skip over the x value where y is clipped at the top and the bottom.

You could solve for f(x) = graphTop and f(x) = graphBottom  or find x for each vertical asymptote, but that can become very difficult for more complex functions.

The easiest way it to do a approximation, unless you are using the graph with a rulers and getting data from it the approximation is as good as the real thing.

To do just reduce the loop step. You had -100 to 100 and I presume you are stepping 1 unit. Rather than step 1 unit step 1/10th or smaller. Don't plot each step, just plot the each unit. But in the sub steps check if the y value is outside the y range.

You have several possibilities from one sub step to the next.

1. Y moving from inside to outside plot
2. y moving from outside to inside plot
3. y moved from outside to outside across plot
4. y moved from inside to inside

For 1,2 we can begin a new path when that happens, for 4 just plot as normal.

The big problem is 3 and there really is no solution apart from eliminating the chance of that happening. To do that you reduce the sub steps, but you can never make them small enough. Consider f(x) = tan(x ^ 2) to catch all case 3's would need a subStep that gets smaller logarithmically, not a good thing when you have a finite CPU resource. So we are left but to do a best fit.

The following will work if the y clip to the left and right of the asymptotes are around 2/10th (`2 / subStepCount` see code for details) pixel apart in the x axis (scaled pixel) but if they get closer it will fail. To increase the sub steps set `var subStepCount = ?`. I added a check to see if the difference between the last two plots is greater than 1/3 of the plots height to catch some of the bad plots.

```js
    
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var h = canvas.height;    
    var w = canvas.width;
    var cw = w / 2; // centers
    var ch = h / 2; 
    var subStepCount = 10;  // number of sub setps
    var scale = 10;         // scale of the plot

  
    function plot(func,col,lineWidth){
        var invScale = 1 / scale;    // inverted scale is the size of a pixel
        var top = ch * invScale;     // get top and bottom
        var bottom = -ch * invScale;
        var subStep = invScale / subStepCount; // get the sub steps between pixels
        var x,y,yy,xx,subX;                    // xx,yy are the coords of prev point
        var start = (-cw - 1) * invScale;      // get the start and end
        var end = (cw + 1) * invScale;
        // set render styles
        ctx.strokeStyle = col;
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth * invScale; // scale line to be constant size

        ctx.beginPath();
        for(x = start; x < end; x += invScale){ // pixel steps
            for(subX = 0; subX < invScale; subX += subStep){  // sub steps
                y = func(x+subX);                    // get y for x 
                if(yy !== undefined){                // is this not the first point
                    if(y > top || y < bottom){       // this y outside ?
                        if(yy < top && yy > bottom){ // last yy inside?
                            ctx.lineTo(x + subX,y);
                        }
                    } else {                         // this y must be inside
                        if(yy > top || yy < bottom){ // was last yy outside
                            ctx.moveTo(xx,yy);       // start a new path
                        }
                        if(subX === 0){              // are we at a pixel 
                            if(y > bottom && y < top){  // are we inside
                                // if the step is large then might be a line break
                                if(Math.abs(yy-y) > (top - bottom) * (1/3)){ 
                                    ctx.moveTo(x,y);  
                                }else{
                                    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if(subX === 0){
                        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
                    }
                }
                yy  = y;
                xx = x+ subX;
            }
        }
        ctx.stroke();

        
    }
        
    // set the plot scale and orientation 
    ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,-scale,cw, ch);
    // two example function plots
    plot((x)=>Math.tan(Math.cos(x/2) * 10),"#F88",1)
    plot((x)=>Math.tan(x),"blue",2)
```

```css
canvas {
   border : 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width = 512 height = 256></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the difference between `radians` and `degrees`. Conversion is relatively simple:

```
//instead of y = Math.tan(x) , use :
y = Math.tan(x * Math.PI / 180);
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/2b3ns745/1/). You can set the starting/ending point of the `x-Axis` in radians by changing the `xAxisPI` variable.

Comment: The thing is, that would mean that every equation user puts would have to be in degrees. http://ensigntrojan.cba.pl/wykresTest.html here you can see the thing I'm working on. It is buggy, and code spaghetti, but hopefully you get what I mean

Comment: @TomaszRadwaski, of course you need to standardize the units of user input somehow. Either have the input in a specific unit, or let the user choose the unit and modify your program to handle that choice. You can't expect to write a magical piece of code that returns right values for both radians and degrees without additional work. If you are working with trigonometric functions, your x-Axis having degrees/radians as its unit makes perfect sense anyways; so I don't see what the problem is here.